# Is this a valid analytic continuation of ζ(s) for 0 < Re(s) < 1?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, analytic-continuation

Given $\zeta(s) = 1^{-s} + 2^{-s} + 3^{-s}...$

$2^{-s}\zeta(s) = 2^{-s} + 4^{-s} + 6^{-s}...$

$\zeta(s)(1-2^{1-s})=1^{-s} - 2^{-s} + 3^{-s} - 4^{-s}...$ which converges for $0 < \Re(s) < 1$.

Is it therefore valid to calculate the output of this convergent series and use it to find values of $\zeta(s)$ in the range $0 < \Re(s) < 1$? If so then is this valid for $\zeta(0)$ also?

Thanks for any help! It will be much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, if $0<\operatorname{Re}s<1$, then$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1^{-s}-2^{-s}+3^{-s}-4^{-s}+\cdots}{1-2^{1-s}}.$$But it is false that $0<\operatorname{Re}(0)<1$.

Comment: Ok thanks! The reason I wondered about ζ(0) is because this formula suggests that as s -> 0 (where s has no imaginary part and s > 0), ζ(s) -> 0. But ζ(0) = -0.5 so does this mean the function is discontinuous as it jumps from s = 0 to s > 0?

Comment: The series representation $$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{1-2^{\,1-s}}\, \eta(s)=\frac{1}{1-2^{\,1-s}}\, \underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{(-1)^{\,n+1}}{n^s}\right),$$ valid for $\Re(s)>0$, alternates between $0$ and $-1$ between successive values of $N$ when evaluated at $s=0$, but $$\underset{s\to 0^+}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{1-2^{\,1-s}}\, \underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{(-1)^{\,n+1}}{n^s}\right)\right)=-\frac{1}{2}=\zeta(0).$$